# Xonar Soundcard only initiated correctly after random number of reboots

Tags: sound, alsa

I have a PC with Ubuntu 16.04 in witch I use both the Gigabyte GA-H97-Gaming 3 onboard Realtek ALC1150 codec (which always gets initialized flawlessly) and a PCI ASUS Xonar Essence ST with H6 Daughterboard soundcard, which needs a random number of reboots before getting initialized.
Prior, on Ubuntu 14.04 it also occasionally (rarely) happened that I had to reboot once (and only once) before the Xonar got initialized.

When the add in soundcards gets initialized correctly it continues to works OK until reboot.

When I look at the PCI bus (with lspci) I always see the Soundcard, whether the Xonar PCI card gets initialized or not but there are only slight differences when the Xonar gets initialized correctly.
`Kernel driver in use: snd_virtuoso`
gets added and its IRQ assigned is 16 (and IRQ 11 if it fails) and the ASMedia PCI bridge ASM1083/1085 changes IRQ 19 to IRQ 15 when it fails

When it works ok the `cat /proc/interrupts` reports for IRQ 16

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
16:        244          2         75          2   IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, snd_oxygen_lib<code>
```

When it fails

```
16:          0          0         28          3   IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
```

And nothing is reported for the in that case assigned IRQ 11 for the XONAR card.

Is there a way that can I make sure that both sound devices always gets initialized correctly.
I tried with sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/rescan" as well as sudo alsa force-reload without success 
Could I add some configuration that always forces the initialization of the device.

Some extra info:
The sound related excerpt of `sudo lspci -v`

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
   Memory at f7c30000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
   Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 15 <= IRQ 19 WHEN INITIALIZED CORRECTLY
    Bus: primary=03, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=32
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge04:01.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Virtuoso 100 (Xonar ST)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 11 <= IRQ 16 WHEN INITIALIZED CORRECTLY
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Capabilities: [c0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: snd_virtuoso # <= ONLY WHEN INITIALIZED CORRECTLY
    Kernel modules: snd_virtuoso
```

The asound kernel version `cat /proc/asound/version`

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.4.0-34-generic.
```

The asound version given by `aplay -version` is version 1.1.0
`cat /proc/asound/modules` when not initialized.

```
 0 snd_hda_intel
 1 snd_hda_intel
```

`cat /proc/asound/modules` when initialized correctly

```
  0 snd_virtuoso
  1 snd_hda_intel
  2 snd_hda_intel
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards` when not initialized

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c30000 irq 30
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7c34000 irq 31
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards` when initialized correctly

```
 0 [STH6           ]: AV200 - Xonar ST+H6
                      Asus Virtuoso 100 at 0xe000, irq 16
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7c34000 irq 31
 2 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c30000 irq 30
```

`aplay -l` when not initialized

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`aplay -l` when initialized correctly

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: STH6 [Xonar ST+H6], device 0: Multichannel [Multichannel]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: STH6 [Xonar ST+H6], device 1: Digital [Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Any messages in the system log (`/var/log/messages`, or the output of `dmesg`) when it fails?

Comment: An awfull lit of messages. No errors and nothing that i can relate to the issue.

Comment: Run, as root, `rmmod snd-virtuoso` and `modprobe snd-virtuoso`. Any new messages?

Comment: Yes when the system booted with the Xonar soundcard in error, then the dmesg command gave some errors related to that soundcard.  

[    1.999752] snd_virtuoso 0000:04:01.0: cannot find the slot for index 0 (range 0-1), error: -16
[    1.999758] snd_virtuoso: probe of 0000:04:01.0 failed with error -16

Comment: I now switched the order of assignment of the soundcards in 
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

options snd_virtuoso index=2
options snd_hda_intel index=0

Comment: So that seems to have solved the problem, or at least covered the timing issue up.

Answer (score 0):

When reordering sound cards, using the drivers' `index` option is dangerous because other drivers could grab the same index.

Instead, use the `slots` option of the `snd` module to assign drivers:

```perl
options snd slots=snd-virtuoso,snd-hda-intel,snd-hda-intel
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will change the reordering method to what you suggest. Until now though the system works 100%. But your comment certainly is helpful as it may better the stability. Thanks again for your appreciated help